# Query results in Perl CGI script is returning back blank webpage with no data

Tags: perl, informix

I am running a script to retrieve passwords for users but I am getting a blank page.  When I check the Apache error logs it is saying it can't locate the Informix Perl Module.  But I installed the Informix Perl Module and I am able to connect to our Informix database through the command line script.

**Error found in Apache Logs:**

```
cgi:error] [pid 30132] [client 10.199] AH01215: install_driver(Informix) failed: Can't locate DBD/Informix.pm in @INC (@INC   contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at (eval 7) line 3., 
referer: server.com/cgi-bin/ts_password_retrieval.cgi [Thu Sep 03  17:58:24.8 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 30132] [client 10.199] 
AH01215: Perhaps  the DBD::Informix perl module hasn't been fully installed,, referer: server.com/cgi-bin/ts_password_retrieval.cgi –
```

**Perl Version and location of Informix libraries:**

```
(v5.16.3)
export INFORMIXDIR=/opt/informix
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$INFORMIXDIR/lib:$INFORMIXDIR/lib/cli:$INFORMIXDIR/lib/esql:$INFORMIXDIR/lib/tools
```

**Code producing error:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w


use CGI::Pretty qw(:standard *table);
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
#use Config::Std;
use vars qw($FICE_CODE $SCHL_NAME $FIRST_NAME $LAST_NAME $TO_ORDER_ID $CH_FLAG $ORDER_STATUS $TO_RECIP_ID $ORDER_STATUS $RECPT_ORDER_STATUS $EMAIL $TO_DELIV_TRANS_ID $PASSWORD $FILE_NAME);
use Data::Dumper;
 #&ReadParse(*input);

 #Output display
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

main();

sub main
{
   print "<html><head>\n";
   print "<title>Transcript Password Retrieval</title></head>\n";
   print "<body>\n";
   print "<center>Transcript Password Retrieval</center>\n";
   print "</body></html>\n";
if (param('to_id'))
    {
    my $to_id = param('to_id');#local to_id
    my $pwd_select = ("select s.fice_code, s.schl_name,   o.first_name, o.last_name, o.to_order_id, o.ch_flag, o.order_status,r.to_recipient_id, r.order_status, r.email, dt.to_deliv_trans_id, dt.password, dt.file_name from to_scprofil s, to_order o, to_recipient r, to_deliv_trans dt where s.to_scprofil_id = o.to_scprofil_id and o.to_order_id = r.to_order_id and r.to_recipient_id = dt.to_recipient_id and o.to_order_id in ($to_id) order by o.to_order_id desc");

    my $driver = "Informix";
    my $database = "Web1";
    my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:dbname=$database";
    my $userid = "todd";
    my $password = "shumer12";
    my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password, {RaiseError => 1}) or die $DBI::errstr;
    #print "Opened db successfully\n";

    my $sth = $dbh->prepare($pwd_select);
    $sth ->execute; #make this a global variable might have to revert this back to a locak variable
    my $rv = $sth->rows;

    while(my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref)
    {
        print hr
        print start_table;
        foreach my $key (keys %$row)
        {
            print Tr
            (
            td(b($key)),
                td($row->{$key}),
            );
        }
        print end_table;
        #print Dumper $row;
    }   
    exit;
my $output = (our @to_pwd);#send output to the array @to_pwd so it can then be spliced into each row

$to_id = format_to_orderid($to_id);
 foreach my $output(@to_pwd)
 {
    ($FICE_CODE, $SCHL_NAME, $FIRST_NAME, $LAST_NAME, $TO_ORDER_ID, $CH_FLAG, $ORDER_STATUS, $TO_RECIP_ID, $ORDER_STATUS, $RECPT_ORDER_STATUS, $EMAIL, $TO_DELIV_TRANS_ID, $PASSWORD, $FILE_NAME)=split(",",$output);#split output with a coma from each row.
        if($FICE_CODE eq "fice_code")#header rows
        {
            print"<tr>/n";
            print"<th>$FICE_CODE</th>";
            print"<th>$SCHL_NAME</th>";
            print"<th>$FIRST_NAME</th>";
            print"<th>$LAST_NAME</th>";
            print"<th>$TO_ORDER_ID</th>";
            print"<th>$CH_FLAG</th>";
            print"<th>$ORDER_STATUS</th>";
            print"<th>$TO_RECIP_ID</th>";
            print"<th>$ORDER_STATUS</th>";
            print"<th>$RECPT_ORDER_STATUS</th>";
            print"<th>$EMAIL</th>";
            print"<th>$TO_DELIV_TRANS_ID</th>";
            print"<th>$PASSWORD</th>";
            print"<th>$FILE_NAME</th>";
            print"<tr/>/n";
            print "</table>/n";
            next;
        }
        print"<tr>/n"; #data information from sql
        print"<td>$FICE_CODE</td>";
        print"<td align 'right'>    $SCHL_NAME</td>/n";
        print"<td align 'right'>    $FIRST_NAME</td>/n";
        print"<td align 'right'>    $LAST_NAME</td>/n";
        print"<td align 'right'>    $TO_ORDER_ID</td>/n";
        print"<td align 'right'>    $CH_FLAG</td>/n";
        print"<td align 'right'>    $ORDER_STATUS</td>/n";
        print"<td align 'right'>    $TO_RECIP_ID</td>/n";
        print"<td align 'right'>    $ORDER_STATUS</td>/n";
        print"<td align 'right'>    $RECPT_ORDER_STATUS</td>/n";
        print"<td align 'right'>    $EMAIL</td>/n";
        print"<td align 'right'>    $TO_DELIV_TRANS_ID</td>/n";
        print"<td align 'right'>    $PASSWORD</td>/n";
        print"<td align 'right'>    $FILE_NAME</td>/n";
        #finish table data html
        print"<tr/>/n";
 }

}
    else
    {
        show_form();
    }
    print"</body></html>\n"
}

sub show_form
{
    my $url = url;
    print qq{<form name="input" action="ts_password_retrieval.cgi" method="get">\n};
    print qq{<table align="center" border="1" bordercolor="black" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">\n};
    print qq{<tr>};
    print qq{<td align="right">Please enter the Transcript Order ID #</td};
    print qq{</tr>\n};
    print qq{<td align="left"><input type"text" width="7" name="to_id" value="">};
    print qq{<BR>Place each Transcript Order ID separated by a space</td>};
    print qq{</table><center><input type="submit" value="Submitted"></center></form>\n};
}
sub format_to_orderid
{
my $in= shift;
my $out = join ',', split /\s/, $in;
return $out;
}
```

**Tried to troubleshoot by just doing a dump_results() and I'm still getting a blank page**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w


use CGI::Pretty qw(:standard *table);
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
#use Config::Std;
use vars qw($FICE_CODE $SCHL_NAME $FIRST_NAME $LAST_NAME $TO_ORDER_ID     $CH_FLAG $ORDER_STATUS $TO_RECIP_ID $ORDER_STATUS $RECPT_ORDER_STATUS $EMAIL $TO_DELIV_TRANS_ID $PASSWORD $FILE_NAME);
use Data::Dumper;
#&ReadParse(*input);

#Output display
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

main();

 sub main
 {
   print "<html><head>\n";
   print "<title>Transcript Password Retrieval</title></head>\n";
   print "<body>\n";
   print "<center>Transcript Password Retrieval</center>\n";
   print "</body></html>\n";
if (param('to_id'))
{
    my $to_id = param('to_id');#local to_id
    $to_id = format_spn_string($to_id);
    my $pwd_select = ("select s.fice_code, s.schl_name, o.first_name, o.last_name, o.to_order_id, o.ch_flag, o.order_status, r.to_recipient_id, r.order_status,r.email, dt.to_deliv_trans_id, dt.password, dt.file_name from to_scprofil s, to_order o, to_recipient r, to_deliv_trans dt where s.to_scprofil_id = o.to_scprofil_id and o.to_order_id = r.to_order_id and r.to_recipient_id = dt.to_recipient_id and o.to_order_id in ($to_id) order by o.to_order_id desc");

    my $driver = "Informix";
    my $database = "Web1";
    my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:dbname=$database";
    my $userid = "user";
    my $password = "password";
    my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password, {RaiseError => 1}) or die $DBI::errstr;
    #print "Opened db successfully\n";

    my $sth = $dbh->prepare($pwd_select);
    $sth ->execute; #make this a global variable might have to revert this back to a local variable
    $sth -> dump_results();
    $sth->finish();
    $dbh->disconnect();


}
    else
    {
        show_form();
    }
    print"</body></html>\n"
}

 sub show_form
 {
    my $url = url;
    print qq{<form name="input" action="ts_password_retrieval.cgi" method="get">\n};
    print qq{<table align="center" border="1" bordercolor="black" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">\n};
    print qq{<tr>};
    print qq{<td align="right">Please enter the ID #</td};
    print qq{</tr>\n};
    print qq{<td align="left"><input type"text" width="7" name="to_id" value="">};
    print qq{<BR>Place each ID # separated by a space</td>};
    print qq{</table><center><input type="submit" value="Submit"></center></form>\n};
}
 sub format_to_orderid
 {
my $in= shift;
my $out = join ',', split /\s/, $in;
return $out;
 }
```

Comment: What results do you get when you run that database query by hand?

Comment: Try perl -c scriptname to see if you have any errors in your script.

Comment: When I run it I get syntax okay.

Comment: I get all of the fields back that I am supposed to get when I run it by hand.  It runs correctly.

Comment: Does your commented out `Dumper` show retrieved data when you enable it?

Comment: There is an `exit` in the code. In a CGI environment, that will result in a blank page.

Comment: let me update my code and run it...

Comment: okay commenting out my while loop and running the dump_results gave me a blank page again:

$sth ->execute; #make this a global variable might have to revert this back to a locak variable
  $sth->dump_results();
  $sth->finish();
  $dbh -> disconnect();
  #my $rv = $sth->rows;
 
  #while(my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref)
  #{
   #print hr
   #print start_table;
   #foreach my $key (keys %$row)
   #{
    #print Tr
    #(
    #td(b($key)),
     #td($row->{$key}),
    #);
   #}
   #print end_table;
   #print Dumper $row;
  #}

Comment: it must be the exit let me take that out and retry.

Comment: I took out the exit and I still receive a blank page.

Comment: still did not answer Oleg: does the Dumper show data? If it does, fetch_row_hashref is not the problem at all, neither is the query. If you comment out everything, that does not help finding the error.

Comment: I added in sth_> dump_results, I didn't comment out everything please see above.

Comment: I'm going to splinter off and put this in a separate perl script and see what results come back.

Comment: If you use CGI, it is possible to pass GET parameters directly as in `perl foo.cgi foo=42 bar=xxx`. This would allow to see exactly what the script outputs and when it stops. Adding some debugging `warn`s and `Dumper`s afterwards would help to isolate the problem and produce a minimal example in which it persists. Hope this helps...

Comment: When placing the SQL in a different script it ran successfully.  It means it's how I am saving and printing the output some where.  Still debugging..

Comment: I've been troubleshooting this all day and can't seem to find why it won't bring back the results when I run it. I've placed up above what I've revised to troubleshoot it.  Any ideas?

Comment: `$to_id` comes from user input and you put it directly in your SQL statement instead of using a parametrized query. Classic SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: No its not.  it's internal use only not on the web.

Comment: Does your webserver's error log show anything suspicious when you access the page?

Comment: @swornabsent Thanks.  No I checked the apache error log and there is nothing "suspicious" in there.

Comment: Was looking in the wrong log swornabsent...I do see some errors there saying it can't find Informix for some reason when I was able to connect to it from a different script.  Let me fix this error.

install                _driver(Informix) failed: Can't locate DBD/Informix.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /u                sr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/sha                re/perl5 .) at (eval 7) line 3.

Comment: Okay this seems to be an issue with the Informix Module possibly? It's saying it can't locate it, but I've installed it and have connected to the database via the command line.  I tried to place use DBD::Informix qw(:ix_types) in, but when I do I get the apache error screen.

Comment: My driver is installed:

support cgi-bin]# perl -w /home/support/automation/driver_list.pl
DBM, ExampleP, File, Gofer, Informix, Multiplex, Pg, Proxy, SQLite, Sponge, mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the Guardian of DBD::Informix — aka developer and maintainer.

Unless you've modified the code in DBD::Informix in ways I don't know about, the notation:

```
my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:dbname=$database";
```

will not work.  Informix does not accept `dbname=` in the connection string (or, more accurately, doesn't interpret it, so it tries to connect to a database called `dbname=whatever@wherever` and fails because `=` is not valid in a database name).

So, drop the `dbname=` part from the DSN.

---

### From `perldoc DBI`:

> #### "connect"
>
> ```
>   $dbh = DBI->connect($data_source, $username, $password)
>             or die $DBI::errstr;
>   $dbh = DBI->connect($data_source, $username, $password, \%attr)
>             or die $DBI::errstr;
> ```
>
> Establishes a database connection, or session, to the requested
>       $data_source. Returns a database handle object if the connection succeeds.
>       Use "$dbh->disconnect" to terminate the connection.
>
> If the connect fails (see below), it returns "undef" and sets both
>       $DBI::err and $DBI::errstr. (It does not explicitly set $!.) You should
>       generally test the return status of "connect" and "print $DBI::errstr" if
>       it has failed.
>
> …
>
> The $data_source value must begin with ""dbi:"driver_name":"". The
>       driver_name specifies the driver that will be used to make the connection.
>       (Letter case is significant.)
>
> …
>
> Examples of $data_source values are:
>
> ```
>   dbi:DriverName:database_name
>   dbi:DriverName:database_name@hostname:port
>   dbi:DriverName:database=database_name;host=hostname;port=port
> ```
>
> *There is no standard for the text following the driver name.* Each driver
>       is free to use whatever syntax it wants. The only requirement the DBI
>       makes is that all the information is supplied in a single string. You must
>       consult the documentation for the drivers you are using for a description
>       of the syntax they require.

*(Emphasis added.)*

### From `perldoc DBD::Informix`

> #### CONNECTING TO A DATABASE
>
> To connect to a database, you use the connect function, which yields a
>       valid database handle if it is successful. …
>
> …
>
> ```
>     $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Informix:$database");
>     $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Informix:$database", $user, $pass);
>     $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Informix:$database", $user, $pass, %attr);
> ```
>
> The DBI connect method strips the 'dbi:' prefix from the first argument
>       and loads the DBD module identified by the next string (Informix in this
>       case). The string following the second colon is all that is passed to the
>       DBD::Informix code. With this format, you do not have to specify the
>       username or password. Note that if you specify the username but not the
>       password, DBD::Informix will silently ignore the username. …

Comment: Thanks Jonathan.  I've changed that, and I'm still getting the same error below on the Apache log?  I can connect to the database fine from the command line and spew back results.  But when I run it as a CGI script I get this error below:

Comment: Update the question with the Apache log information that looks relevant.  Which version of Perl, DBI, DBD::Informix are you using, on which platform?  What is different between the environment of your CGI script and your command line script?  The key difference will be one of those, almost certainly.

Comment: But the Informix module is installed:

[root@sandbox cgi-bin]# perl -w /home/support/automation/driver_list.pl                                                                                                                               
DBM, ExampleP, File, Gofer, Informix, Multiplex, Pg, Proxy, SQLite, Sponge, mysq                                                                                                                               l

Comment: The error message shown says that Perl can't find your driver reliably.  Did you by any chance build it with `DBD_INFORMIX_RELOCATABLE_INFORMIXDIR`?  Where is it installed if you think it is installed?  Is the CGI using the same copy of Perl as you use on the command line?

Comment: I don't think I set that variable when installing.  I just did an echo for that variable and it isn't there.

Comment: You probably didn't set it (`DBD_INFORMIX_RELOCATABLE_INFORMIXDIR`); it's a mouthful (fistful?) to type, which is good because I don't really want people typing it — though there are reasons to use it for some people.  Are the Informix libraries installed in the correct place?  Have you changed the location of `$INFORMIXDIR` perchance?

Comment: That's a good point to see if CGI is using the same version of Perl as the command line.  I don't think there are two versions of Perl unless we pulled down one separately from yum and it is using the one that came in the LAMP package.  Let me see what I can find and see what details I can get from our SA.

Comment: Okay let me go back and look at the README for the setup of the mouthful(fistful) variable and what I should set it to.  I think it should be "YES" or "NO".  Will check on this when I get logged back in to the VM.

Comment: The DBD_INFORMIX_RELOCATABLE_INFORMIXDIR is now set:

-support sbin]# echo $DBD_INFORMIX_RELOCATABLE_INFORMIXDIR
yes

Comment: How can I change how APACHE is getting the PATH variables?  It is looking here:

/usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at (eval 7) line 3., 
referer: server.com/cgi-bin/ts_password_retrieval.cgi [Thu Sep 03  17:58:24.8 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 30132] [client 10.199]

Comment: I'm sorry if I misled you, but `DBD_INFORMIX_RELOCATABLE_INFORMIXDIR` is not the default partly because it's easier to use DBD::Informix with web servers etc if it is not relocatable. However, it can be made to work; you just have to ensure that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or your local equivalent is set to pick up `$INFORMIXDIR/lib` and `$INFORMIXDIR/lib/esql`. With that done, the remaining problem is setting the PATH for Apache. Succinctly, "I'm not sure" (I'm not an Apache admin), but Server Fault says [Setting Apache 2 PATH environment variable](http://serverfault.com/questions/151328).

Comment: Oh I see I misunderstood what you meant.  Okay yes those library paths are correctly set for PATH.  Thank you for that link and your help on this will try this and update if this works.